# Turn off cookies visual studio webbrowser

Tags: vb.net, cookies

I'm writing a program using vb and i have 2 webbrowsers in it.
I have to open the same site in both of them, and login with 2 different accounts, but when i login to 1, and refresh the other one, it logs in to the same account automatically.
I think this is because of cookies, and i was wondering how to turn these off.
I've tried to find something like this in the settings of the webbrowser, but with no succes.
Thanks in advance!
Also, you can do this in internet explorer using `-nomerge`, so i need this in vb.

Comment: post the code you are using to login/browse

Comment: Basher, thanks for the answer, but to login i use my keyboard, and to browse my mouse, might sound like a joke, but i do it manually since i dont know how to login via a script

Answer (score 0):

Try reading up on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9y96tw7t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.HTMLDOCUMENT.COOKIE%29%3bk%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION%3dV4.0%22%29%3bk%28DevLang-VB%29&rd=true&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

You might wanna get and set the Webbrowser.Document.Cookie property for both browsers